# 'Video Card 0 isn't in look-up file' when attempting to play Age of Mythology through Remote Desktop?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, windows-xp, age-of-mythology

I am trying to run Age of Mythology through Remote Desktop. The reason for this is my Windows 7 Machine isn't powerful enough, but my Windows XP machine is.

So, I am running

- Age of Mythology on Windows XP Pro SP3
- Remote Desktop running on Window 7 Pro SP1

I get the message from AOM stating:

> Video Card 0 doesn't have device id or vendor id, and <rdpdd.dll> isn't in look-up file.

Is there a way to fake it out?

I have tried TeamViewer but it renders too slow. TightVNC has too much lag and appears to skip frames. AOM plays fine on the PC that I installed it, just not when I remote over to it.

I have not tried to install on the Windows 7 machine, since it's not a that great a PC.

Comment: @Aequitas - I don't think this is a Steam copy of AoM

Comment: It can be played via RD. But you have to config it right (sadly I'm not as much help, I don't recall how I had it configed. Try making sure your remote desktop session is sharing graphics and sound (and before you do that, make sure you have a good NIC on both computers (wired), and a good connection between them... either way, I wouldn't expect the best. The lag is because the game has to render, then send the data to the remote computer which then renders again...no matter what you're going to have some amount of lag.

Comment: @Aequitas - Also: Steam Remote Play is [not supported from Windows XP Hosts](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3629-RIAV-1617#knownissues)

Comment: @Robotnik oh good pickup

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you want isn't possible:

> Microsoft's RDP uses a it's own graphics driver which converts the rendered screen into network packets to send to the client.
>
> This is the core of how RDP works and you cannot change it.
> <sub>- [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/690613/107240)</sub>

---

Unfortunately, your Windows XP host poses a bit of a problem. It means that Steam's [In-Home Streaming](http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/) will not work as per their [Support Page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3629-RIAV-1617#knownissues).

Your best option is to try out [SplashTop](http://www.splashtop.com), which currently still supports Windows XP. They have different prices, however the personal tier is free. I cannot personally vouch for it's quality but [reports](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/1mh2o5/are_you_able_to_play_pc_steam_game_with_remote/) I've read online seem to be pretty good.

#### References

- [Super User: Remote Desktop Graphics Card](https://superuser.com/a/690613/107240)
- [MSDN: Remote Desktop Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com)
- [Splashtop FAQ](https://support-splashtoppersonal.splashtop.com/categories/20046452-Frequently-Asked-Questions)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/1mh2o5/are_you_able_to_play_pc_steam_game_with_remote/)